# combine mid and substitute

Tags: excel, substitution

Is it possible to combine the MID or RIGHT function with the Substitute function and make that conditional on the value of another cell.

I have two columns one is a product code, starting from the 8th character there are 3 letters that correspond to the color and then after that there are 3 characters for the size (this is the end so would use right function)

Assuming A1 looks like this xxxxxx-BLK30C and B1 says color then i want to extract the MID(8,3 BLK in this example). If B1 says Size i want to extract the 3 from the RIGHT.

Then if it's a colour i would like to substitute the 3 letter code for the actual word, e.g "Blk" becomes "Black", "BLU" becomes "BLUE"

Thanks

Comment: something like: `=IF(B1="Colour",LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),3),RIGHT(A1,3))`  Will return your colour and size as required.... you can then use a `vlookup()` or something similiar to change the colour from BLK to Black. ie something like `=IF(B1="Colour",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),3),G13:H14,2,FALSE),RIGHT(A1,3))` 

Assuming that `G13:H14` has the lookup array

Comment: The only issue with how Ive done it is that Ive specifically searched for the last 3 characters for size, and last 6 to 3 for colour. You will need to use a `Find()` to make it a bit more generalised

Answer (score 1):

*The simple answer:* `Substitute` won't help you here...

```
=IF(B$1="color",MID($A2,8,3),IF(B$1="size",RIGHT($A2,3),""))
```

If you really want to spell out the colors, you'll need a little table somewhere to lookup the full spelling.  Easy way would be to make this cell range and *name* it `colors`:

> BLK | Black
>
> BLU | Blue

And use this formula:

```
=IF(C$1="color",VLOOKUP(MID($A2,8,3),colors,2),IF(C$1="size",RIGHT($A2,3),""))
```

Or you could make it a table (named `colors`) and get the same effect in a more well defined manner...

```
=IF(D$1="color",INDEX(colors[Description],MATCH(MID($A2,8,3),colors[Code],0)),IF(D$1="size",RIGHT($A2,3),""))
```

Comment: Thanks both, i'll give these a try!